# HTTP Response Status Codes in IE

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer

For example, I get 12150 instead of 301. Anyone knows anything about that?

Comment: `HTTP/1.2 12150 Please ask a real question` :)

Comment: An example would be nice. The question as stated now is impossible to answer (or so I believe).

Comment: Read it at http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/1450 for an example.

Comment: Do you have an example URL where we can all see this behaviour?

Comment: @Voropie stop spamming the site with non-questions.

Comment: @Voropie: Pekka's point is that there's *very little* detail in your question. You don't include any example client-side code explaining how you're making the request. You don't include an example URL where the problem can be reproduced. The title of the question is neither a question nor a description of a problem. I *would* edit all that myself, but I'm not clear exactly what's going on, so don't really feel qualified to.

Comment: @Voropie: This is not how StackOverflow works. We are spending our free and valuable time to help you with your problems. None of us gets paid for this. Be polite. We need more detail to help in this case.

Comment: You're talking about an XMLHttpRequest's `status` property, yeah? When a connection fails at an HTTP level, IE will give you a Windows error code here (other browsers just give you `0`). [List of Windows error codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681381%28VS.85%29.aspx). 12150 is for when a required header is not supplied in the response, for example a `301` response with no `Location` header.

Answer (score 1):

It could be the following:

```
ERROR_HTTP_HEADER_NOT_FOUND
12150
The requested header could not be located.
```

Try installing [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and try it again and see the raw headers that are returned.